# Unable to Create Session using org.openqa.selenium.devtools.DevTools.createSession

Tags: maven, timeoutexception, chrome-devtools-protocol, selenium4

When I run the sample program below:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.devtools.DevTools;
import org.openqa.selenium.devtools.v101.security.Security;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;
 
public class TestBadSSL {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        DevTools devTools = ((ChromeDriver) driver).getDevTools();
        devTools.createSession();
        devTools.send(Security.enable());
        devTools.send(Security.setIgnoreCertificateErrors(true));
        driver.get("https://expired.badssl.com");
    }
}
```

in my office maven project (where various dependencies are added for automation testing of a website), I am facing the following issue:

> Seen: {method=Target.attachedToTarget,
> params={sessionId=44499725D2AB375AD1B774158ADF17C7,
> targetInfo={targetId=E598228D3883B0864B295A2E8FB60BCC, type=page,
> title=data:,, url=data:,, attached=true, canAccessOpener=false,
> browserContextId=CD23CAB248BAF68DCF73116B99D44DEF},
> waitingForDebugger=false}}
>
> Exception in thread "main"
> org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException:
> java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException Build info: version:
> '4.0.0-alpha-2', revision: 'f148142cf8', time: '2019-07-01T20:55:26'
> System info: host: 'UE-M-LAP-1105', ip: '192.168.250.92', os.name:
> 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version:
> '16.0.2' Driver info: driver.version: unknown     at
> org.openqa.selenium.devtools.DevTools.createSession(DevTools.java:99)
> at testcases.SSR.EnquiryForms.t.main(t.java:22) Caused by:
> java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException     at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.timedGet(CompletableFuture.java:1956)
> at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:2091)
> at
> org.openqa.selenium.devtools.DevTools.createSession(DevTools.java:88)
> ... 1 more

I am stuck please help, Chrome Ver: Version 101.0.4951.41

My Maven Project POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>  <groupId>CRM</groupId>  <artifactId>CRM</artifactId>    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
        </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                    <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
              <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
                    <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
               <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
               <version>1.7.30</version>
           </dependency>

           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
               <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
               <version>4.0.0-alpha-2</version>
           </dependency>

           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
               <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
               <version>4.0.0-alpha-2</version>
               <exclusions>
                   <exclusion>
                       <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                       <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                   </exclusion>
               </exclusions>
           </dependency>


           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
               <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
               <version>1.21</version>
           </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-alpha-2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.beust</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jcommander</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                    <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
               <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
               <version>1.68</version>
           </dependency>

           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
               <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
               <version>4.0.0-alpha-2</version>
           </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-devtools-v101</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>netty-buffer</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                    <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                    <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
               <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
               <version>5.1.3</version>
               <exclusions>
                   <exclusion>
                       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                       <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                   </exclusion>
               </exclusions>
           </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.auto</groupId>
            <artifactId>auto-common</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.auto.service</groupId>
            <artifactId>auto-service</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

           <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>31.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
                    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
                    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

           <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
               <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
               <version>1.18.24</version>
               <scope>provided</scope>
           </dependency>

           <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.30</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.codoid.products</groupId>
            <artifactId>fillo</artifactId>
            <version>1.21</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>bson</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-testng-adaptor</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.4</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

           <dependency>
               <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
               <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
               <version>2.9.0</version>
           </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-examples</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-excelant</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.virtuald</groupId>
            <artifactId>curvesapi</artifactId>
            <version>1.06</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.15</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
            <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
            <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
            <artifactId>ant-launcher</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.9</version>
        </dependency>

           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.beanshell</groupId>
               <artifactId>bsh</artifactId>
               <version>2.0b4</version>
           </dependency>

           <dependency>
            <groupId>com.beust</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcommander</artifactId>
            <version>1.82</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.10</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mongodb-driver-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
                    <artifactId>bson</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.36.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.beust</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jcommander</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
                    <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

           <dependency>
               <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
               <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
               <version>1.4.01</version>
           </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.9</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            <version>1.24</version>
        </dependency>

           <dependency>
               <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
               <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
               <version>1.7.30</version>
               <scope>test</scope>
           </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.25.0-GA</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies> </project>
```

Answer (score 0):

There a few incompatibility issues:

- CDP 101 for Chrome & ChromeDriver v101 is only supported by Selenium Java 4.1.4, see [selenium/java/CHANGELOG](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/6083cc471d7dba85a439068d28c3c1ab01c8644f/java/CHANGELOG). Update the project to use 4.1.4
- amend the getDevTools() call to `DevTools devTools = driver.getDevTools();`

Also if the purpose of the test is to only ignore the cert error use ChromeOptions, to avoid CDP compatibility issues, do the following and you can use your current project configuration:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

public class TestBadSSL {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.get("https://expired.badssl.com");
    }
}
```